# Return a Distinct Result Set Across Multiple Tables - DB2

Tags: db2, db2-400

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT V.COMPANY, V.VENDOR_NUM, V.VENDOR_PAYEE_NUM,
  C.CONTACT_NAME, C.CONTACT_AUDIT_DATE
  FROM
       VENDOR_TABLE AS V INNER JOIN CONTACT_TABLE AS C ON (V.COMPANY = C.COMPANY AND DIGITS(V.VENDOR_NUM) = C.VENDOR_NUM)
       WHERE DATE(INSERT(INSERT(DIGITS(V.VENDOR_AUDIT_DATE), 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-    ')) >= DATE(VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP_ISO(CURRENT DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) - 21 DAYS
       AND V.VENDOR_AUDIT_DATE <> 0 AND (V.STATUS = ' ' OR V.STATUS IS NULL)
```

It returns the following result:

> ```
> COMPANY   VENDOR_NUM  VENDOR_PAYEE_NUM V  CONTACT_NAME                    CONTACT_AUDIT_DATE
> -------   ----------  ----------------    ------------------------------  ------------------
>     908        13514             13514    Coleen                          20120427
>     908        34242             34242    Frank Cheese                    20100120
>     908        60148             60148    Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe              20141121
>     908        60148             60148    Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe              20141121
>     908        60151             60151    Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe              20140919
>     908        60151             60151    Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe              20140919
>     908        60152             60152    Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe              20140919
>     908        60152             60152    Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe              20140919
> ```

The contact table may have multiple contacts for the same vendor. However, I only want to pull back one contact per vendor number retrieved from the vendor table. How do I join these tables, yet only select 1 or distinct vendor contact from the Contact table per vendor from the Vendor table?

I modified my query a bit. I found that there is a sequence number on the contact table that I can manipulate. I would need the max sequence in that record set. However, I keep receiving an error, "Column CZCO or expression in SELECT list not valid". I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong...Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT COMPANY, VENDOR_NUM, VENDOR_PAYEE_NUM,
  VENDOR_NAME, COUNTRY_CODE, ADDRESS_1,
  ADDRESS_2, CITY_STATE, ZIP_CODE,
  PAY_ADDR_1, PAY_ADDR_2, PAY_CITY_STATE,
  PAYEE_ZIP_CODE, VENDOR_AUDIT_DATE
  FROM VENDOR_TABLE V 
  INNER JOIN
  (
  SELECT CONTACT_KEY, COMPANY, CONTACT_PHONE,
  CONTACT_FAX, CONTACT_EMAIL, CONTACT_NAME,
  CONTACT_AUDIT_DATE, MAX(SEQ_NUM) AS SEQ_NUM
  FROM CONTACT_TABLE GROUP BY CONTACT_KEY
  ) C ON (V.COMPANY = C.COMPANY AND DIGITS(V.VENDOR_NUM) = C.CONTACT_KEY)
  WHERE DATE(INSERT(INSERT(DIGITS(V.VENDOR_AUDIT_DATE), 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-')) >= DATE(VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP_ISO(CURRENT DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) - 20 DAYS
    AND V.VENDOR_AUDIT_DATE <> 0 AND (V.STATUS = ' ' OR V.STATUS IS NULL)
```

Comment: You marked query as 'oracle' and 'oracle11g'
but query doesn't look like Oracle query. 
'INSERT', 'DATE', 'DIGITS' are not oracle SQL functions. 
Are they user-defined?
Also seems that result-set is not full or from another query, because 'DISTINCT' keyword will not return duplicated rows (but in your result-set they exists).

Comment: You are correct. Sorry for the confusion. This is DB2. I will update the heading. Thank you.

Comment: aka [tag:greatest-n-per-group].  I don't see how you're getting the results you claim, given you have `DISTINCT`, but you list actual duplicate rows.  Also, your query won't be able to use an index to fulfill the date range search (since you're doing string concatenation on the search side); try converting the value returned on the right into the formatted string/digits (or converting the type to `DATE`, if possible).  Although that date handling is more complicated than it needs to be anyways...

Comment: Thank you, I can eliminate the where clause, which pulls back any changes in the last 21 days, and I am faced with same issue. I only want one (the latest) contact information in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use the keep dense rank function to group by something and keep the rest of it together.

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT   908 AS company,
                    13514 AS vendor_num,
                    13514 AS vendor_payee_num,
                    'Coleen' AS contact_name,
                    20120427 AS contact_audit_date
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   908,
                    34242,
                    34242,
                    'Frank Cheese',
                    20100120
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   908,
                    60148,
                    60148,
                    'Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe',
                    20141121
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   908,
                    60148,
                    60148,
                    'Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe',
                    20141121
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   908,
                    60151,
                    60151,
                    'Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe',
                    20140919
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   908,
                    60151,
                    60151,
                    'Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe',
                    20140919
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   908,
                    60152,
                    60152,
                    'Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe',
                    20140919
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   908,
                    60152,
                    60152,
                    'Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe',
                    20140919
             FROM   DUAL)
  SELECT   company,
           vendor_num,
           vendor_payee_num,
           MIN (contact_name)
              KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY contact_name, contact_audit_date)
              contact_name,
           MIN (contact_audit_date)
              KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY contact_name, contact_audit_date)
              contact_audit_date
    FROM   sample_data
GROUP BY   company, vendor_num, vendor_payee_num



COMPANY VENDOR_NUM  VENDOR_PAYEE_NUM    CONTACT_NAME    CONTACT_AUDIT_DATE

908 13514   13514   Coleen  20120427
908 34242   34242   Frank Cheese    20100120
908 60148   60148   Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe  20141121
908 60151   60151   Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe  20140919
908 60152   60152   Sarah Lee/Jonh Doe  20140919
```

Comment: you tagged this as oracle but you want DB2 my solution was for oracle however you can replicate a KEEP in DB2. see the following  http://www.zinox.com/archives/165

Comment: Why not simply use `MIN()` aggregate?

Comment: Thank for your response. Although, I haven't been able to get this to work for me.